# Getting crash in iOS App for [GAIDataStore coordinatorWithModel:URL:], [GAICoreDataUtil entityWithDescription:]

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, google-tag-manager, firebase-analytics

I am using following google pods

```
pod 'GoogleTagManager'
pod 'Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK'
pod 'GoogleIDFASupport'
pod 'GoogleSignIn'

pod 'Firebase/Auth'
pod 'Firebase/RemoteConfig'
pod 'Firebase/Performance'
pod 'Firebase/Crashlytics'
pod 'Firebase/Analytics'
```

getting following crashes in Crashlytics

```
-[GAIDataStore coordinatorWithModel:URL:]
+[GAICoreDataUtil entityWithDescription:] 

FirebasePerformance
-[FPRSelectorInstrumentor initWithSelector:class:isClassSelector:]
__48-[FPRNetworkTrace updateTraceWithCurrentSession]_block_invoke
-[FPRSelectorInstrumentor initWithSelector:class:isClassSelector:]
```

How can I fix it?

using xcode 13.1

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

For the FirebasePerformance crash, `pod update` to at least Firebase 8.6.0. Details at https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/8495

Comment: Thanks for reply Paul, but i am using 8.8.0 pod version of Firebase